# Create S-curve between 2 points (easing) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm working on some trajectory generation for a robotics project. It moves the torso of the robot up and down during a gait cycle.

When I change the setpoint of the torso I currently create a straight line between the current position and the desired position using `linspace()`. However I want to ease the start and the end of the line. I want to create an S-curve to prevent shocks at the start and the end of the line.

I have looked at using a sigmoid function `sigmf(x,[a c])` but I don't know what the dependency is of the `a` and `c` variable with regards to the distance between the 2 points.

How can I use MATLAB to generate a smooth S-curve between 2 points to ease the endpoints of the line?

Example:

I have 2 points: `y = 0.9` and `y = 0.3`. I need to create an S-curve which starts at `x=0` and ends at `x=1000`

The x axis will always be between `0` and `1000` the y axis will always be within `[0 1]` or `[1 0]`

Comment: See my answer.  You have two equations for two unknown constants a and c.  It's an easy matter to solve for them to allow a smooth transition between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB docs give you some clues:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/sigmf.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

A little playing around should make it clear, but the parameter a appears to mean "start of rise/fall" and c means "midpoint of the transition where the value of the S curve is 0.5".

Best of all, it gives you the exact formula it's using.  You can easily plot it out for different values and see how it behaves.

Your real problem might be that you'll need to repeatedly solve for appropriate constants a and c given a start and end point.  Two unknowns a and c; two equations, one each for start and end point.  You should solve for closed form expressions for a and c for a given start and end point and then use the resulting curve to allow a smooth transition between them.

Comment: I have updated my question a bit because I can only get it to decrease. Perhaps you could show me a small example?

Comment: I would expect a MATLAB user to be astute enough to solve two equations for two unknowns.